# How to hide next and previous buttons for a single image in carousel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, carousel, owl-carousel

I am working on a website in which I want to place **next and previous** buttons on **images** so that its easy for the users to navigate through the images.

The php code which I have used with carousel classes are:

```
<div class="text-center border-right px-0">
   <div id="owl_item_images" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <?php
         if(isset($data['item']->media))
         {
         foreach ($data['item']->media as $media)
         {
         echo '<div class="item">
         <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
         <img class="item_images_carousel" src="'.$media->url.'">
         </div>
         </div>';
         //'.$media->url.';
         }
         }
         ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

The HTML code rendered at the front end is:

```
   <div id="owl_item_images" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
      <div class="owl-stage-outer owl-height" style="height: 350px;">
         <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-7677px, 0px, 0px); transition: 1.5s; width: 8530px;">
            <div class="owl-item">
               <div class="item">
                  <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
                     <img class="item_images_carousel" src=".jpg">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 853px;">
               <div class="item">
                  <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
                     <img class="item_images_carousel" src=".jpg">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-nav disabled">
         <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
         <div class="owl-next">next</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-dots">
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
          -
          -
          -
          -           
         <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should do in the **PHP code** **(as html code is rendered at the front end)** above so that  previous/next buttons are visible.

**UPDATE:**

On removing display none I can see next and previous buttons but I am wondering still how I can hide next and previous buttons from a single image.

```
 <div class="owl-nav disabled">
             <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
             <div class="owl-next">next</div>
 </div>

.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled, .owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
    /* display: none; */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For owl carousel navigation is disabled by default. We have to enable it while initializing the carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
     nav : true;
  });
});
```

You can refer this [link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) for additional options

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am just checking if you got my question.

Comment: I have used your code  `$('#owl_item_images').owlCarousel({
       nav : true
    });` but now all the images are visible instead of hiding behind the carousel.

Comment: In order to make it simple, I have made the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97j9gmtm/656/embedded/result) for my code above. If there are multiple images `next and previous buttons should show up`, and if there is `one image no next and previous buttons should show up`.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://search.ruckify.com/item/cf90a1e0-5753-11e8-8726-8765ee31d6e8) for the website for which I am working on. For multiple images, there should be `next and previous buttons` but for one image there should be `no next and previous button`.

Comment: in your custom.js file, around line no. 70, add

`nav: true,`

please check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/97j9gmtm/661/

Comment: Thanks it worked. You really saved my precious time.

Comment: I have one more similar question. Stay tuned.

Comment: It is related to the homepage of the website, the `featured posts` section. If you open the homepage of the website, I don't want empty spots when we navigate the images left/right. I am wondering what changes I need to do so that there are no empty spots when we navigate the images towards the right.

Comment: You can use infinite loop.. So there will be continuation of slides and it never ends..

`loop : true,`

Comment: where do I need to add loop:true, ? I am not sure...Can you have a look from the website ?

Comment: If I am correct, the class you are using for initialize the home page carousel is 'owl_items' . If so you need to add this option along with the initialization of the carousel. And it seems like on your 25th line of custom.js

Comment: Checking, stay tuned.

Comment: So what I need to do is `I need to add loop:true, on line no. 25th in custom.js file right ?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177634/discussion-between-hakkim-and-flash).

Answer (score 0):

The owl-carousel will automatically disable the owl-prev and owl-next if there is only one item in the list.

So first verify that you have more than one item in the list. Try examples with increasing numbers of items and see when/if owl-prev and owl-next appear. There is logic in the library to disable the control under certain circumstances.

Otherwise look to link below that suggests ways to change the owl library class to avoid the problem under certain circumstances.

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1809

Comment: I have more than one image in a list. I am wondering how to enable next and previous buttons if there are more than one images.

Comment: @user5447339 It **should** work properly if the total number of images is greater than the number visible on the screen. However, some users report there is a bug in the library and they have to modify it to make it work. Read the link I gave above. Otherwise all I suggest is try another carousal, there are many!! :-)

Comment: @user5447339 on second thoughts, its hard to see from your HTML what possible interaction of classes may be occurring. Solve a simpler problem, by going back to the "get-started" examples at the OwlCarousal2 site.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i fully understand your question but maybe remove "disabled" from here:

```
<div class="owl-nav disabled">
```

Comment: Removing that will definitely work, but how to remove next and previous buttons for single image ? Is there any way we can remove next and previous buttons for single image ?

Comment: For single image, I am still thinking how to remove next and previous buttons.

Comment: Not really used owl carousel but came across this by adding the "onInitialize" option when initializing your carousel... https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1519

Comment: How can I integrate this in my current php/html code ?

Comment: Where do you initialize the carousel? Should look something like like this..

`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});`

Comment: I can't find this in my code. I am using `owl.carousel.min.css` and `owl.theme.default.min.css` , and `owl.carousel.min.js`

Comment: I have edited my question. May be it can help you now.

Comment: Is it your code or have you copied and pasted it? You need to find where you have initialized the carousel. Just as Hakkim has posted.. You shouldn't need to edit the css..

Comment: I have edited the css but editing does not solve the problem how can we hide next and previous buttons when there is only single image in carousel ?

Comment: You need to find `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(); });` in your code it will be in your <script></script> tags or a seperate js file

Comment: `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();` is how the carousel is initialized. It has to be in your code for it to show..